# Add Click event to menu item

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have created a context menu that appears  when the user right-clicks. I cant figure out how to call a form when one of the menuitems is clicked. see my code below.

```
if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
{
    ContextMenu m = new ContextMenu();
    m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("New"));
    m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("-"));
    m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Old"));
    m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Lost"));
    m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("-"));
    m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Found"));

    switch(m.Name)
    {
        case "New":
            new FrmInfo().ShowDialog();
            break;
    }
```

Comment: I cannot find `ContextMenu` type, but cant you just do something like, `m.MenuItems["New"].OnClick += OnClick;`?

Comment: Why don't you use `ContextMenuStrip`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [MenuItem(String, EventHandler)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c524thtw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) constructor, it takes OnClick event handler as second argument.

So your code could look like

```
m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("New", MenuItemNew_Click));

...

private void MenuItemNew_Click(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    new FrmInfo().ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: how would you add sub menu items in that context?

Comment: @HeseinBurg Exactly the same way as usual: just populate that new menuitem `MenuItems` collection before adding it to `m.MenuItems`

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this :

```
ContextMenu menuContainer = new ContextMenu();
var menuItem = new MenuItem("New");
menuItem.Click += Menu_Click;
menuContainer.Items.Add(menuItem);
```

And the event handler will be defined as :

```
void Menu_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //here comes your code
}
```

Comment: This is the 'usual' way to add event handlers to System.Windows.Forms objects. Interesting that menuItem constructor also takes a parameter accepting the EventHandler for the clickEvent. Unusual for System.Windows.Forms objects

Answer (score 1):

"New" is the Text property of a MenuItem, not the ContextMenu.

MenuItems also have event handlers, so you can run some code when a specific menu item is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Inherit item data from ICommand:

```
public class EscalateData : System.Windows.Input.ICommand
    {
        ITV.Misc.Msg m_react = null;
        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello world!");
        }
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "Menu item";
        }
```

Then fill up context Menu:

```
ContextMenu GenerateContextMenu()
{
    var ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
    
    var escalate = new MenuItem() { Header = "Main" };
    List<EscalateData> data = new List<EscalateData>();
    data.Add(new  EscalateData());
    data.Add(new  EscalateData());
    ContextMenu.Items.Add(escalate);
    escalate.ItemsSource = data;
    return ContextMenu;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to add click event to menu items on a menu stripe one can do as follows:

```
private void menuStrip1_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
{
    string itemText = e.ClickedItem.Text;


    switch (itemText)
    {
        case "menu name 1":
            //do stuff
            break;

        case "menu name 2":
            // do stuff
            break;
    }
}
```